Tensorflow (CPU) not running on Debian WSL
On a Debian/WSL2 setup without GPU I try running the following code but it returns me errors. I installed Pytorch as well, hoping it would resolve some TF error, but it didn't resolve the issue wholly. I merely wanted to complete the huggingface tutorial on my laptop. Any ideas to debug it?
from transformers import pipeline

data = ["I love you", "I hate you"]

specific_model = pipeline(model="finiteautomata/bertweet-base-sentiment-analysis")
specific_model(data)

Output:
$ python3 HelloWorld/test.py
2024-12-23 09:33:35.046787: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:477] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1734942815.063438    1495 cuda_dnn.cc:8310] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
E0000 00:00:1734942815.068390    1495 cuda_blas.cc:1418] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-12-23 09:33:35.084911: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
emoji is not installed, thus not converting emoticons or emojis into text. Install emoji: pip3 install emoji==0.6.0
Device set to use cpu

My setup:
$ pip list
Package                      Version
---------------------------- ----------
absl-py                      2.1.0
astunparse                   1.6.3
certifi                      2024.12.14
charset-normalizer           3.4.0
filelock                     3.16.1
flatbuffers                  24.3.25
fsspec                       2024.12.0
gast                         0.6.0
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.68.1
h5py                         3.12.1
huggingface-hub              0.27.0
idna                         3.10
Jinja2                       3.1.5
keras                        3.7.0
libclang                     18.1.1
Markdown                     3.7
markdown-it-py               3.0.0
MarkupSafe                   3.0.2
mdurl                        0.1.2
ml-dtypes                    0.4.1
mpmath                       1.3.0
namex                        0.0.8
networkx                     3.4.2
numpy                        2.0.2
nvidia-cublas-cu12           12.4.5.8
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12       12.4.127
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12       12.4.127
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12     12.4.127
nvidia-cudnn-cu12            9.1.0.70
nvidia-cufft-cu12            11.2.1.3
nvidia-curand-cu12           10.3.5.147
nvidia-cusolver-cu12         11.6.1.9
nvidia-cusparse-cu12         12.3.1.170
nvidia-nccl-cu12             2.21.5
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12        12.4.127
nvidia-nvtx-cu12             12.4.127
opt_einsum                   3.4.0
optree                       0.13.1
packaging                    24.2
pillow                       11.0.0
pip                          23.0.1
protobuf                     5.29.2
Pygments                     2.18.0
PyYAML                       6.0.2
regex                        2024.11.6
requests                     2.32.3
rich                         13.9.4
safetensors                  0.4.5
sentencepiece                0.2.0
setuptools                   66.1.1
six                          1.17.0
sympy                        1.13.1
tensorboard                  2.18.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.7.2
tensorflow                   2.18.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.37.1
termcolor                    2.5.0
tf_keras                     2.18.0
tokenizers                   0.21.0
torch                        2.5.1
torchaudio                   2.5.1
torchvision                  0.20.1
tqdm                         4.67.1
transformers                 4.47.1
triton                       3.1.0
typing_extensions            4.12.2
urllib3                      2.3.0
Werkzeug                     3.1.3
wheel                        0.45.1
wrapt                        1.17.0

$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.2

$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm


These don't look like errors. These look like warnings, and warnings that you could ignore if you only want to use the CPU model. The line specific_model(data) will run the model on your data, but not print the results or save them anywhere. Is that intentional, or did you mean something like print(specific_model(data))?

Indeed, I wanted to print the Output. Silly me simply followed the tutorial and it seemed like running these lines should provide the printed output, whereas the print statement is missing.

As suggested by Nick ODell this isn’t a mb error but warnings. The model is loaded and in order to see the output the print statement is needed!
